# How to cancel the creation of a context menu after onCreateContextMenu() has been called

Tags: android, android-listview, contextmenu

I have an activity that registers a list view for the creation of the context menu:

```
registerForContextMenu(getListView());
```

The problem is that a long click on some items should not present the context menu, because the items are disabled.

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    bool bDisplayMenu = isItemEnabled(((AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo).position);

    if(bDisplayMenu)
    {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
    }
    else
    {
        // WHAT SHOUlD I DO HERE TO CANCEL THE CREATION OF THE CONTEXT MENU?
    }

}
```

I don't see any way to cancel the creation of the context menu once onCreateContextMenu() has been called.

Comment: @LEO87 it turned out that if I return from onCreateContextMenu() without creating a menu (just calling super.onCreateContextMenu()) then the menu will not appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it turned out that if I exit from onCreateContextMenu() immediately after calling super, then the context menu doesn't appear at all.

Not sure this is the way to go (I didn't see any documentation regarding this).

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    bool bDisplayMenu = isItemEnabled(((AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo).position);

    if(bDisplayMenu)
    {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
    }
    else
    {
        return; // the context menu will not be displayed
    }

}
```